# Why is the exposed api undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gojs

I am trying to expose the api of one of my directives to another, container directive.
Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('palette', ['paletteNodesProvider', function (paletteNodesProvider) {

return {

    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'assets/templates/palette.html',
    scope: {

        api: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
        var palette = $(go.Palette, 'nodesPalette', {

            nodeTemplateMap: paletteNodesProvider.getTemplateMap(),
            layout: $(go.GridLayout)
        });

        var nodeDataArray = paletteNodesProvider.getNodeData();
        var linkDataArray = [];

        palette.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray, linkDataArray);

        scope.requestUpdate = function () {

            palette.requestUpdate();
        };

        scope.getTitle = function () {

            return 'My nodes';
        };

        scope.api = {

            getTitle: scope.getTitle,
            requestUpdate: scope.requestUpdate
        };
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {


    }]
};
}]);
```

In the container I try to setup the binding:

```
<palette api="api"></palette>
```

But in the container when I try to console log $scope.api, or call $scope.api.requestUpdate via ng-click, I always get that $scope.api is undefined. 
I am using Angular 1.6.
I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

EDIT:

This is the full html of the container directive:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true"
               style="white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
            <div ng-click="testing()">
                My nodes
                <i class="pull-right glyphicon"
                   ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': dir.isHeaderOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !dir.isHeaderOpen}"></i>
            </div>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        <palette api="api"></palette>
    </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

EDIT2: 
I guess the problem could be that both directives are creating an isolated scope?

Comment: Why're you replacing the `api` in the link function?

Comment: no, I wasn't, unless you mean the fact that I define the api in the link function, but that shouldn't  be a problem. Also, the same problem (undefined) persists even if I put everything in the controller of the palette directive.